# Ruby/JS Waveform sorting of the array in the format of arr[0] <= arr[1] >= arr[2] <=arr[3]

Tags: ruby, sorting, waveform

I have an array and i want to shuffle that array in a wave form Ruby but the format will be

> ***arr[0] <= arr[1] >= arr[2] <=arr[3] ......***

> Input: [2,1,5,3,11,7]
> Output: [2,7,3,11,1,5]

Comment: Okay. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have tried something like this:


(a.length - 1).times do |i|
    a[i], a[i + 1] = a[i + 1], a[i] if i.even? && (a[i] > a[i + 1])

    a[i], a[i + 1] = a[i + 1], a[i] if i.odd? && a[i] < a[i + 1]
  end

Comment: You can shuffle the given array then step through permutations of its elements until you find an array having the desired property, if one exists. That provides an unbiased sampling procedure, but it may of course be very time-consuming. I'm doubtful, however, that a more efficient procedure exists for which each feasible solution has an equal probability of being drawn (which is what is meant by "shuffling").